# How to use Android Beacon Library to scan NOT JUST Beacon devices, but also the normal ble devices?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am currently use Android Beacon Library to receive beacon adverts and everything goes well.

However, I have to use BluetoothAdapter to find another BLE devices and communicate with them.

Can I use Android Beacon Library to find the normal BLE devices(not the beacons)?
If positive, how to accomplish it?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: @ligi That is the other main functionality of my app. I need to find another BLE devices and communicate with the certain one of them(if more than one I found) to perform something.

Comment: yes but why do you want to use the beacon-lib for it and not the normal bluetooth API? Sounds wrong ( like using a screw-driver to hammer a nail - sure it is possible but .. )

Comment: @ligi Actually I used to use normal bluetooth api to do so. However, the scanning and communications became much slower after I use this Library to listen for beacons. I wonder if the Library is always using BluetoothAdapter which is the only one for entire system when I require for it . Therefore I am trying to figure out if I can mix the normal scanning for the BLE devices and iBeacon with the library. That is why I want to use the beacon-lib for it.

Comment: Ah OK - this makes sense - do you use altbeacon lib?

Comment: @ligi Yes, I am currently using Android Beacon Library for discovering iBeacon Signal. So I am wondering how Can I discovery normal BLE devices by [this Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html)

Comment: @ligi Any idea that can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can use Android Beacon Libraries to discover ble devices including iBeacons and ordinary beacons.

Comment: Sorry,  I want to discover both iBeacons and normal BLE devices, but not ordinary beacons which I think would it be slightly different from BLE devices, right?

Comment: Yes.They are different.Which library are you using for this?

Comment: I am currently using [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html)